# jquery windows heigth iOS7

Tags: jquery, safari, ios7

it seems that jQuery windows height doesn't return correct value on Safari iOS7

```
$(window).height();
```

do i have to add jquery mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pretty comprehensive review of the problem:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/window-height-mobile-safari-and-the-iphone-address-bar